# How to show/hide an element in real time (Blazor)?

Tags: forms, blazor

I have an image I would like to display only after a user has filled in all text fields.

I have tried using `disabled` attribute, but that does not seem to work. Any other insights?

Here is my current code:

```
<EditForm EditContext="@EditContext" style="max-width:800px;" onkeydown="javascript: DisableEnterKey();">
            <FluentValidator />

            <img src="images/approval-16-grey.ico" alt="Image" disabled="@OkayDisabled">


            <p class="statp">How many families and/or individuals are living on your land?</p><br />

            <label class="statlabel" for="amountOfFamilies">Amount of families:</label><br />
            <InputNumber id="fams" for="indivNum" class="input" @bind-Value="@familyData.IndividualAmount" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="Families..." autofocus />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => familyData.IndividualAmount" />

            <br /><hr class="statHR" />

            <label class="statlabel" for="amountOfIndividuals">Amount of single individuals: </label><br />
            <InputNumber id="individuals" for="famNum" class="input" @bind-Value="@familyData.FamilyAmount" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="Individuals..."/>
            <ValidationMessage For="() => familyData.FamilyAmount" />

            <br /><hr class="statHR" />

            <label class="statlabel" for="names"> Please enter all of the names here:</label><br />
            <InputTextArea id="names" class="textArea" rows="4" cols="18" @bind-Value="@PersonName" placeholder="Names of all individuals..." />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => familyData.PersonName" />


        </EditForm>

        </div>
    </ul>


    @code 
    {
        private EditContext? EditContext;
        public FamilyData Model = new FamilyData();

        protected string OkayDisabled { get; set; } = "disabled";

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            EditContext = new EditContext(Model);
            EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;

            base.OnInitialized();
        }

        protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
        {
            base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);

            SetOkDisabledStatus();
        }

        private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetOkDisabledStatus();
        }

        private void SetOkDisabledStatus()
        {
            if(EditContext.Validate())
            {
                OkayDisabled = null;
            }
            else
            {
                OkayDisabled = "disabled";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Change `OkayDisabled` to a `bool`, and then around your image do this

```
@if (!OkayDisabled)
{
  <img src=".....whatever" etc />
}
```

You might also want to add `@bind:event="oninput"` wherever you use an `@bind`.

Comment: Yes! This was the only way I could get the element to show and hide.  I tried with the hidden tag, no dice, don't waste your time, do it like this.

Comment: I think this is the more "Blazor way" of doing this specific task.

Comment: this will work but when the content of the if is huge then it will be harder to trace/maintain

Comment: @VJPPaz That is nothing to do with the solution I provided. What you are talking about is breaking down complex markup into components.

Comment: when implementing this solution you need to consider, that if instead of an `<img ... />` a component is being rendered, the lifecycle methods of said component will be triggered every time the `@if(condition)` switches to true. This might be an issue if the component used `IJSRuntime` to change the DOM.

Answer (score 56):

The `hidden` html attribute also works to hide an element.

`<p hidden>This paragraph should be hidden.</p>`

To bind to Model:

```
 <p hidden="@HideLabel">I am Hidden When HideLabel == true</p>

 <p hidden="@(!HideLabel)">I am Hidden when Hidelabel == false</p>
    
 <button @onclick="@Toggle">Show/Hide</button>

 @code {
      private bool HideLabel { get; set; } = false;
      private void Toggle()
      {
         HideLabel =   !HideLabel;
      }      
 }
```

Edit: You can also use a CSS class to hide/show an element:

```
<div class="font-italic @(HideLabel ? "d-none" : "d-show")">
   I am Hidden When HideLabel == true
</div>
```

Comment: Here I am, two years later, reading my own answer.

Comment: we've all been there

Comment: @GregGum sometimes I even come back for the good old times ;)

Comment: @GregGum "Hello old friend"  https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/27/2020-stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/#h2-bfa52674d2140

Answer (score 7):

Instead of binding your flag to the disabled attribute (an image's disabled attribute just [grays it out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-dom-input-image-disabled-property/#:%7E:text=The%20HTML%20DOM%20Input%20Image,and%20are%20unusable%20and%20unclickable.)), I would bind it to a css class that has `display: none;`

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```
<img class="@(ShouldShowImage? "hidden" : string.Empty)">
```

Comment: I actually use this method the most.  Bootstrap has a style call "d-none" so I use `<img class="@(ShouldShowImage? "d-none" : "d-show")">`     d-show is not a real class, it's just a fake class to show the intention of showing it.

Answer (score 3):

didn't used it within editform but should work

```
 @if(OkayDisabled) 
 {
  <img src="images/approval-16-grey.ico" >
```

Comment: That code doesn't work, as you have it, having made up for the error

Comment: How can I make OkayDisabled hold true/false for if all the fields are filled?